# Method not allowed when I do curl GET

Tags: curl, web-applications, http-status-code-405

I'm running a small webapp which should allow the following curl:

```
curl -I http://localhost:5000/yield
```

It gives me this 405 response though:

[image]

Does this mean my webapp doesn't allow this method or the server doesn't allow it and how do I resolve this? I'm on Windows 2019 Server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`curl -I` makes a `HEAD` request, not a `GET`. Some servers simply disables the ability to do `HEAD` requests - I've never understood why.

The `Allow:` response header there implies that this server only accepts `GET` on that resource, so try again without `-I` ? (maybe use `-i` instead of you want the headers too).

You can also use `-v` to get to see the headers, but then they're not passed to the same destination as the body, as `-i` does. You decide!